# EXCEL-VBA/MACRO inserting picture

Tags: excel, vba

I place the data in a table on the sheet I use to print labels.

I was able to place the data in the cells I wanted, but I could not add the logo.

How can I place the logo starting from row 3 in column C?

```
Sub etiket()

    Dim i As Long, st1 As Byte, st2 As Byte, st3 As Byte
    Dim st4 As Byte
    
    Dim yol As String
    yol = "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\labelexample\logo.jpg"

    Sheets("etiket").Select
    Range("A3:A" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
    
    st1 = 1: st2 = 2: st3 = 3: st4 = 4
    
    With Sheets("veri")
        sat = 3
        For i = 5 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            
            **Cells(sat, "C") = Set MyPict = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(yol)** ' this is error line
            Cells(sat, "E") = .Range("A4")
            sat = sat + 1
            Cells(sat, "E") = .Cells(i, st1)
            sat = sat + 4
            Cells(sat, "C") = .Range("B4")
            Cells(sat, "D") = .Range("C4")
            Cells(sat, "E") = .Range("D4")
            sat = sat + 1
            Cells(sat, "C") = .Cells(i, st2)
            ' sat = sat + 1
            Cells(sat, "D") = .Cells(i, st3)
            ' sat = sat + 1
            Cells(sat, "E") = .Cells(i, st4)
            sat = sat + 4
            
        Next i
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Picture insertion is completed, but it added as many images as the number of records in the selected cell. it is not added to the cell I specified.

trying to make this label:
[image: PICTURE IS STANDART AND ALWAYS THE SAME]

Comment: Move that line to between the `sat=3` and `For i=5 To....` line.  It's putting it on every row as you've put it within the loop.  Moving it before the loop will just place it on row 3 - the initial value for `sat`.

Comment: thanks but I want it to repeat as many times as the number of records anyway.

Comment: images are not placed in the gridlines of an Excel sheet. They are more floating above. You need to move them to the position you need with Top and Left.

Comment: @Andreas can i give 4 different position with vba ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do like this:

```
Sub etiket()

    Dim i As Long, st1 As Byte, st2 As Byte, st3 As Byte
    Dim st4 As Byte
    
    Dim yol As String
    yol = "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\labelexample\logo.jpg"

    Sheets("etiket").Select
    Range("A3:A" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
    
    st1 = 1: st2 = 2: st3 = 3: st4 = 4
    
    With Sheets("veri")
        sat = 3
        For i = 5 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            
            ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(yol).select ' this is error line
            Selection.ShapeRange.Top = Cells(sat, "C").Top
            Selection.ShapeRange.Left = Cells(sat, "C").Left

            Cells(sat, "E") = .Range("A4")
            sat = sat + 1
            Cells(sat, "E") = .Cells(i, st1)
            sat = sat + 4
            Cells(sat, "C") = .Range("B4")
            Cells(sat, "D") = .Range("C4")
            Cells(sat, "E") = .Range("D4")
            sat = sat + 1
            Cells(sat, "C") = .Cells(i, st2)
            ' sat = sat + 1
            Cells(sat, "D") = .Cells(i, st3)
            ' sat = sat + 1
            Cells(sat, "E") = .Cells(i, st4)
            sat = sat + 4
            
        Next i
    End With
    
End Sub
```

If I understand your code correctly then this will add a logo, and move it to the position of "C" & sat top left corner.
You can add a few pixels if you want like this:

```
            ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(yol).select ' this is error line
            Selection.ShapeRange.Top = Cells(sat, "C").Top + 5
            Selection.ShapeRange.Left = Cells(sat, "C").Left + 5
```